# Const struct in D

Tags: struct, constants, d

I am trying to pass a struct as a compile time argument to a function.
I think the code is self explanatory. I am fairly certain that this should work. But I don't know why it won't work.

```
void main(string[] args)
{
    const FooStruct fooStruct = FooStruct(5);

    barFunction!fooStruct();
}

public struct FooStruct()
{
    private const int value_;
    @property int value() { return value_; }

    this(int value) const
    {
        value_ = value;
    }
}

public static void barFunction(FooStruct fooStruct)
{
    fooStruct.value; /// do something with it.
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public struct FooStruct()
```

Here, you're declaring FooStruct to be a templated struct, with no variables. If that's what you want, you'll need to refer to `FooStruct!()` on this line:

```
public static void barFunction(FooStruct fooStruct)
```

Since `FooStruct` takes no template arguments, there's not really any need for it to be templated, and you should probably declare it like this:

```
public struct FooStruct
```

When you do that, the error message changes to `constructor FooStruct.this (int value) const is not callable using argument types (int)`. That's because you're invoking the mutable constructor. To fix that, change line 3 to read `const FooStruct fooStruct =`**`const`**`FooStruct(5);`.

Finally, when you call `barFunction`, you are attempting to pass `fooStruct` as a template parameter (`barFunction!fooStruct()`). Since `barFunction` is not a templated function, this fails. You probably meant `barFunction(fooStruct)`.

Comment: I see I reduced my question to this example and made some translation errors. But you understood what I wanted. It seems that I didn't do 'const FooStruct fooStruct = const FooStruct(5);' but instead did 'const FooStruct fooStruct = FooStruct(5);' which made the error. The more you know.